# Responsive mobile navbar (navigation) jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design

I was making a responsive web design but I came across this problem with my jquery. Whenever I try to open my menu when in mobile size then it simply opens for a second and closes quickly even before I can click on the menu button. When I change .css('display', '') to .css('display', '500') the menu works but then the problem is that when I close the mobile menu then my full desktop website nav menu doesn't show. How can I fix this so that my navbar works in mobile and in desktop and tablet views?

I kept my phone/tablet/dektop .css files separately instead of making @media and would prefer to keep it that way if possible. (if you've got any questions about the code just feel free to ask and thank you in advance for taking time helping me with this.)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
    jQuery(".menubutton").click(function() {
        
        jQuery(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '')
        //the number next to 'display' '' can be turned into 1 but then the menu of desktop doesn't show
        });
        
    });
    
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* cssphone */

.menubutton {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-size: 6vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* Navigation java*/
.nav-expanded {
    display: block;
}

/* Navigation java end*/

.nav-menu {
    display: none;
}

nav ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #680000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px black dashed;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

nav ul li:active {
    border-bottom: 3px #fff dashed;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.currentnav {
    border-bottom: 3px #fff dashed;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-size: 6vw;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #680000;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul li:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

/* css phone ends */


/* css desktop */

@charset "utf-8";

.menubutton {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #680000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

nav ul li:active {
    border-bottom: 3px #fff solid;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.currentnav {
    border-bottom: 3px #fff solid;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #680000;
    min-width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -2px;
}

nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul li:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

/* css desktop ends */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYLE html>
<html class="html" lang="en">


<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssdesktop.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 599px)" href="cssphone.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 960px)" href="csstablet.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo%2016x16.png" alt="16x16logo">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo%2016x16.png">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jsfiles/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jsfiles/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="homepage" link="orange" vlink="blue" alink="yellow">
 

  <div class="menubutton">MENU</div>
  <nav class="nav-menu"> 
    <ul>
   <li class="currentnav"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li>
   <a href="Gamin'_News.html">News</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Latest_Gamin'_News.html">LGN</a></li>
          <li><a href="Games_Coming_Out_requirements.html">Games Coming out/Requirements</a></li>
          <li><a href="Technology_News.html">Technology News</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li><li>
   <a href="Gameplay.html">Gameplay</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Counter_Strike_Global_Offensive.html">CS</a></li>
          <li><a href="The_Elder_Scrolls_Online_Tamriel_Unlimited.html">TESO</a></li>
          <li><a href="Other_Games.html">Other Games</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li><li>
   <a href="F.A.Q..html">F.A.Q.</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Cookies.html">Cookies</a></li>  
        </ul>
      </li><li>
   <a href="About.html">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Who_am_I.html">Who am I?</a></li>
          <li><a href="Facebook.html">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="Twitch.html">Twitch</a></li>
          <li><a href="Youtube.html">Youtube</a></li>
        </ul>  
      </li><li>
   <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
  </nav>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated your code in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k4zL1rap/ 
I've had to change a few css properties to display block so I could see the nav, but the issue was with the code below:

`.css('display', '')` You are already displaying block with the class toggle, so the extra display was then removing the display value as you have an empty string in the js. Also there should be a semi-colon at the end of that line for future reference.

Comment: This code is fine and makes everything work except the desktop view. Of course I can get to the menu but by clicking on the menu button but what I really wanted is for the menu button to only show in mobile form but not in desktop form. So essencially I want the (view=desktop) nav always visible without the menu button (menu button now visible), and in (view=mobile) I would like the menu button to be visible but the nav only visible when clicked on.

Comment: You just need to have a media query wrapped around the display properties like this `@media all and (max-width: 500px) .menubutton {
    display: block;}`